# enable manual date entry on prime faces calendar

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to allow the user to type a date manually in the TextBox of Prime facesCalendar.
here is my code :

```
 <p:calendar id="birthDate" size="22" locale="#{view.locale}"
                            maxdate="#{userCreation.maxDate}" navigator="true"
                            yearRange="c-100" readOnlyInputText="false"
                            value="#{userCreation.user.birthDate}"
                            mindate="01/01/1900" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            style="left: 194px !important;">
                        </p:calendar>
```

is there an attribute i can use without having to craft my own JavaScript solution?

thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of PrimeFaces are you using? For example on [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarBasic.jsf) it is not problem to enter date manually without any additional attributes or JavaScript.

Comment: Also there is no attribute called `readOnlyInputText`, there is `readOnlyInput` whose default value is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you will do

> readOnly= true or false

Calendar component will allow user to manually enter date..(true or false)Flag indicating that this input element will prevent changes by the user.For more information you can check Primefaces Tag Documentation [Here](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/calendar.html)